# Save a IXMLDOMDocument3 to xml-file in runtime with Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

If I would like to save a IXMLDOMDocument3 in runtime to a file on my harddrive, what is the syntax for that?

E.g. like IXMLDOMDocument3.save('c:\test.xml')

Or is it even possible?

Best regards!

Comment: what is wrong with `Save` method? it does exactly what you need. see remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

the sample code below demonstrates how to load and save `IXMLDomDocument3` XML at runtime. It uses msxml header file from Delphi-2010. `IXMLDomDocument3` inherits from `IXMLDomDocument` and has `Save` method (as you wrote in your question). If method parameter is a string, then it specifies file name (it creates or replaces target file).

```
program Project3;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, msxml, comObj, activex;

    procedure LoadAndSaveXML(LoadFile, SaveFile : string);
    var xml : IXMLDOMDocument3;
        tn : IXMLDOMElement;
    begin
        xml := CreateComObject(CLASS_DOMDocument60) as IXMLDOMDocument3;
        xml.load(LoadFile);
        xml.save(SaveFile);
    end;
begin
  try

    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
        LoadAndSaveXML('D:\in.xml', 'D:\out.xml');
    finally
        CoUninitialize();
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: For Delphi 2007 you can import the type library from 'msxml6.dll', or you can use `CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0')` for late binding.